# How do these Möbius transforms arise?

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I am reading Henri Cartan's *Elementary Theory of Analytic Functions of One or Several Complex Variables*. Below is exercise 10 (p.111) in chapter 3:

> Let $f$ be a holomorphic function in the disc $|z|<1$, such that $|f(z)|<1$ in this disc; if there exist two distinct points $a$ and $b$ in the disc such that $f(a)=a$ and $f(b)=b$, show that $f(z)=z$ in the disc. (Consider the function $g(z)=\frac{h(z)-a}{1-\bar{a}h(z)}$, with $h(z)=f\left(\frac{z+a}{1+\bar{a}z}\right)$, for which $g(0)=0$, $g\left(\frac{b-a}{1-\bar{a}b}\right)=\frac{b-a}{1-\bar{a}b}$, and $|g(z)|<1$ in the disc.)

The exercise itself is easy if we follow the hint. It's just a simple application of Schwarz's lemma. However, the constructions of $g$ and $h$ here seem too magical to me. **How does one come up with the hint?** Does it originate from some special trick about Möbius transform?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, it should be $h(z)=f\left(\frac{z+a}{1+\bar{a}z}\right)$.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for catching the typo. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to consider
$$
 g = T \circ f \circ T^{-1}
$$
where $T$ is an automorphism of the unit disk with $T(a) = 0$. Those automorphism are well-known and in fact Möbius transformations, see for example

- [Proof that automorphisms of unit disk are of the form $\lambda \dfrac{z-a}{\overline{a}z-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2797325/proof-that-automorphisms-of-unit-disk-are-of-the-form-lambda-dfracz-a-over)
- [Automorphisms of the Unit Disk](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_18/unit%20disk%20maps.pdf)

Then $g(0) = 0$ and $g(T(b)) = T(b)$, so that the Schwarz lemma can be applied to $g$.

Comment: I haven't learned this before. It makes a lot of sense. Thanks very much!